# Powershell, Need to input IP in racadm command

Tags: powershell

I would like to validate a list of DRAC IP's using racadm.  I created a powershell script to go through each IP and the run the racadm to get the sysinfo.  I'm very new to powershell and hoping get some assistance in get a result sent to a csv file with serverName and getsysinfo.

```
$dracList = import-csv .\currentDracList.csv -header("Server_Name","Ilo_drac_ip")
$results = @()
$dracList | % {

    $dracIP = $_.Ilo_drac_Ip

        $dracProps = @{
            racadm -r $dracIP -u root -p P@ssword! Getsysinfo
            }
    $resultt += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $dracProps
}

$Result | export-csv .\dracResults.csv
```

Currently getting an error:

```
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
t line:4 char:22
             racadm -r <<<<  $dracIP -u root -p P@ssword! Getsysinfo
```

I'm able to run the command one at a time, hoping to come up with a good script to run against IP's.

CSV file contains two columns, "Server_Name","Ilo_drac_ip" as mentioned in the script.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.  It would be great to have the Server_Name appear in the results.

Thanks,

Comment: I can sort of see what you are trying to do. Right now you are trying to declare a hash table without using the "key=value" syntax. `racadm` does return something similar but in a string format. You need to look at [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx) which makes a hash table from a key=value string

Comment: What info do you want? Converting that to a csv would be easier if you narrow down the data set you are looking for.

Comment: Else the issue have is that there are multiple entries for `Enabled =` in the output which violates a hashtable since it has to be unique key/value pairs.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will try to add the convertfrom-StringData.  I need to capture the results of getsysinfo.  I will hold a key/value in the response for model/firmware version/hardware version/IP etc.  I would like to grab that and save in any format as long as I can read the data.

An example:
RAC Date/Time           = Tue Mar  3 23:33:22 2015
Firmware Version        = 1.65
Firmware Build          = 12.08.16
Last Firmware Update    = Wed Jul 24 13:56:25 2013

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it on a Single server. Maybe this can put you a step closer to a solution.

```
$ipv4 = (racadm getsysinfo -4) | Select-String -Pattern "Current IP Address" | 
ConvertFrom-StringData
$result = $ipv4."Current IP Address"
$result
```